# Why is TestNG throwing a "javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: validation is not supported" error

Tags: ant, xml-parsing, testng

I'm getting an error after upgrading my implementation of TestNG to 6.13.1 from 6.11. I have an ANT build (tried the build on ANT 1.9.4 and 1.10.1 with the same failure) that triggers a TestNG suite containing one class. After doing all the ANT setup stuff, it calls TestNG to start test execution and I immediately get the following error:

```
[testng] javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException: validation is not supported
[testng]    at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:100)
[testng]    at org.testng.xml.XMLParser.<clinit>(XMLParser.java:29)
[testng]    at org.testng.xml.Parser.<clinit>(Parser.java:34)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.parseSuite(TestNG.java:290)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeSuitesAndJarFile(TestNG.java:334)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.initializeEverything(TestNG.java:974)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:988)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1330)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1299)
[testng] [TestNG] [ERROR] java.lang.NullPointerException
[testng] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.getStatus(TestNG.java:206)
[testng]    at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:1300)
[testng] The tests failed.
```

Here is my build.xml:

```
<project name="6 - GW Testing" default="resolve" xmlns:ivy="antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant">
<property name="lib.dir" location="C:/dev/.ivy2/cache" />
<property name="res.dir" location="../TestNGReports" />
<property name="GWPersistence.ivy.file" value="C:/tmp/svncheckouts/guidewire/GWPersistenceIvy/gwpersistence-ivy.xml"/>
<property name="GWBroker.ivy.file" value="C:/tmp/svncheckouts/guidewire/GWBrokerIvy/gwbroker-ivy.xml"/>
<property name="GWRepository.ivy.file" value="C:/tmp/svncheckouts/guidewire/GWRepositoryIvy/gwrepository-ivy.xml"/>
<property name="GWServices.ivy.file" value="C:/tmp/svncheckouts/guidewire/GWServicesIvy/gwservices-ivy.xml"/>
<property name="GWTesting.ivy.file" value="C:/tmp/svncheckouts/guidewire/GWTestingIvy/gwtesting-ivy.xml"/>
<property name="Local.config" location="C:/tmp/regression-configs/guidewire" />
<property name="Regression.config" location="${Local.config}/suite" />

<path id="lib.classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="**/*.jar" />
    </fileset>
</path>

<path id="combined.classpath">
    <path refid="lib.classpath" />
</path>

<target name="init" description="initialize the build environment">
    <tstamp />

    <delete dir="${res.dir}" />
    <mkdir dir="${res.dir}" />

    <delete dir="C:/Users/qauser/.ivy2/cache/com.idfbins.guidewire" />
</target>

<target name="resolve" depends="init" description="retrieve dependencies with ivy">
    <ivy:configure file="C:/dev/.ivy2/ivysettings.xml" />

    <ivy:resolve file="${GWPersistence.ivy.file}" />
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" />

    <ivy:resolve file="${GWBroker.ivy.file}" />
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" />

    <ivy:resolve file="${GWRepository.ivy.file}" />
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" />

    <ivy:resolve file="${GWServices.ivy.file}" />
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" />

    <ivy:resolve file="${GWTesting.ivy.file}" />
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" />

    <ivy:resolve file="../GWRepositoryConfig/suite/ivy.xml" />
    <ivy:retrieve pattern="${lib.dir}/[conf]/[artifact]-[type]-[revision].[ext]" />
</target>

<target name="run-tests-a-test-runner" depends="resolve">
    <taskdef name="testng" classpathref="lib.classpath" classname="org.testng.TestNGAntTask">
        <classpath>
            <pathelement location="../../lib/default/testng-6.11.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </taskdef>

    <delete file="${Local.config}/config.properties" />
    <copy file="C:/tmp/svncheckouts/guidewire/GWRepositoryConfig/suite/regression-test-runner.properties" todir="${Local.config}" />
    <rename src="${Local.config}/regression-test-runner.properties" dest="${Local.config}/config.properties"/>
    <echo message="CONFIG FILE: regression-test-runner.properties copied to config.properties" />

    <echo message="Running Tests..." />
    <testng classpathref="combined.classpath" outputDir="${res.dir}" haltOnfailure="false">
        <classpath location="combined.classpath" />
        <xmlfileset dir="C:/tmp/svncheckouts/guidewire/JobXMLFiles" includes="a-test-runner.xml"/>
    </testng>
  </target>
</project>
```

And here is my suite declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="A-Test-Runner" verbose="1">
<test name="A-Test-Runner">
    <classes>
        <class name="regression.r2.clock.billingcenter.cancel.TestCancellationOnBoundPolicy" />
    </classes>
</test>
```

So far, I have tried to remove the DTD in the suite declaration, I've change pathing around every which way, And tried various versions of ANT and TestNG. So far, the only thing I have been able to get to work is to revert back to TestNG 6.11. I'm at a loss as to what is going on here. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your CLASSPATH is resolving you to an external parser which is causing this. I think you are probably resolving to the [pull-parser](https://www.extreme.indiana.edu/xgws/xsoap/xpp/).

I am saying this because I see

`at org.gjt.xpp.jaxp11.SAXParserFactoryImpl.newSAXParser(SAXParserFactoryImpl.java:100)`

in your exception.

You can try getting past this by forcing Java to fall back to the default parser available in JDK by specifying it via

`-Djavax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory=com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl`

Comment: THANK YOU! You pointed me in the right direction. It turns out that Hibernate was causing problems for us. The fix was to exclude the dom4jj jar that was included with it and include a newer version. I didn't realize until I dug into it, that the org declaration in Ivy changed for dom4j at some point, so we were using an old version (circa 2007) of dom4j. This jar is what contained xpp3. Updating to the new dom4j module (from 09/2017) fixed it perfectly for us. I still think it is using xpp3, but it's now able to parse my xml file. Thank you again. You're a lifesaver!

Comment: In fact your own comment should be right answer. In our case it was pull-parser dependency pulled by dom4j.

Ofc @Krishnan Mahadevan answer is legit but it should be resolved by root cause if external parser is not used in application

Comment: @IvanBaranuk I also got same issue and resolved by disabling transitive dependencies coming from dom4j. May be what you said is right. It is pulling new parser. Thanks for your help and saving me a hell amount of time